# SharedPreferences on higher Api-Level Not working?

Tags: android, api

In order to release my App in the Play Store, I had to change the `TargetSdkVersion` from `23` to `26`.
Before I changed it, the App worked perfectly!
Now the App crashes on start.
I figured out, that the problem was at these two lines:

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences("de.bs.quicknoteblock.Notes", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        editor = prefs.edit();
```

Now my Question is, how I can use `SharedPreferences` with `Api-Level 26`

Comment: Provide error message please

Answer (score 1):

`Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` is deprecated, replace it with `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`

Answer (score 0):

hi I think your problem is the SharedPreferences code please test this way

> (maybe should change Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE to
>   Context.MODE_PRIVATE is work ! )

first please download this source code and add your project , [download](http://ufile.io/hapau)

so after add you can use SharedPreferences so esay sample code :

```
   // class A --- > save text in SharedPreferences 

    new AppPreferenceTools(context, "Share") .savePreferences("test","simple text"); 

    // class B ---> read text as SharedPreferences 

String text = new AppPreferenceTools(context, "Share").getName("test",defultSTR);
```